# iOS 11 Navigation issue when status bar is hidden

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, ios11

When status bar hide that time how to set navigation height on **iOS 11**? I used custom navigation & its worked for **below version of iOS 11**. I set navigation height 48 **below version of iOS 11** & its worked fine but not worked on **iOS 11**. I tried to fix this issue from many days but still not getting any idea.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344381/ios-11-layout-guidance-about-safe-area-for-iphone-x

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i am not talking about iPhoneX. Other device as well. Please refer link in which i added 8+ screen shot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/123itwbtrt8ft4g/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPhone%208%20Plus%20-%202017-11-13%20at%2012.42.59.png?dl=0