# iOS app honor iPhone X screen constraints without using iOS 11 API

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, custom-controls, iphone-x

I have an app that needs to run on iOS9 - 11 and on iPhones other than X.  I have built it with XCode 9 so that it gets the full iPhone X screen, but I can't seem to get it to display correctly with the notch.  My app uses a custom UI view that draws itself within the bounds of the view (a fullscreen view).  It Currently draws itself right underneath the notch.  What I would like to do, is have it behave as it does in iOS9+ with iPhone 5+, but on an X draw a fullscreen backdrop, but only use the area away from the notch for interacting with the user.  This includes both the top when in portrait but also the side when the phone is in landscape.  I basically want to extend my insets to allow a margin under the notch so the user buttons are not obscured, as they currently are.  I have tried safeLayoutBounds but can only seem to access that via the iOS11 only API.

To restate, I want to use the space for background use, but scoot controls, etc, away from the notch.  So I would like to know:
1 - The screen size (which I already have),
2 - that the notch is there - which I assume I only tell by the phone model and orientation,
3 - What the bounds are that the notch covers so I can avoid it.

Here are two screen shots to illustrate, if it isn't clear.  Sorry for the size, I tried to adjust them smaller:

**Landscape notch covers buttons**
[image: Landscape notch covers buttons]
**Portrait it covers the display**
[image: Portrait it covers the display]

Comment: Use should use safe area layout guides for autolayout.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344381/ios-11-layout-guidance-about-safe-area-for-iphone-x

Comment: Do you have the layout in storyboard or in code ?

Comment: The main UIView is in a storyboard, and I enabled safe layout guides, but I didn't change any constraints yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first - maybe foremost, why should **any** iPhone X be running anything but iOS 11? (Hint: it takes a downgrade.)

Having said that, the trick is to (a) check the iOS version being run then (b) understand what *else* was introduced in iOS 11 - namely, safety areas.

Because I needed to know more *exact* dimensions of this *safe area* I added an invisible, lowest-level view. I'm thinking you could take my code and see how to apply it to your needs:

```
let safeAreaView = UIView()
....
safeAreaView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
safeAreaView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(safeAreaView)
....
view.sendSubview(toBack: safeAreaView)
```

And the layout:

```
let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
view.addLayoutGuide(margins)

if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    safeAreaView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    safeAreaView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
} else {
    safeAreaView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    safeAreaView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
safeAreaView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
safeAreaView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Net result? You have a view you can base the remaining layout on. Yes, It gives spots that *are not* in the "safe" area. Change the `backgroundColor` to see what I mean.

I'm sure there are better ways to determine (a) the actual height of this `safeView` or (b) to account for something. But this should work for iOS 11, iOS 10, iPhone X, iPhone SE.

More, it works with AutoLayout.

Comment: My question might not have been clear, but I am not trying to support iPhone X running iOS < 11, I want my app to run on all iPhones and look right on iPhone X.  I don't want to use iOS 11 programmatic APIs because I don't want to limit compatibility.

Comment: I haven't used the #available feature before - I assume it allows your code to compile and run on both.  I will give that a try.

Comment: Yes, that's what `if @available` does. To get a quick look at what the safe area is, change the color from `UIColor.clear` to something else (I like orange!) and pretty much put the above code in an empty project. It presents it's own challenges, depending on your layout.